# How do I maximize windows behind Ubuntu dock?

Tags: gnome-shell, window, ubuntu-dock, appearance

I would like to make maximized windows reach behind the launcher (or dock), to improve appearance. Currently items can reach behind it, but not when using the maximize option.

[image: my desktop]

As you can see the applications window here is maximized, but there are gaps (top right and down right) and you can see a part of my desktop background.

I don't want the launcher to hide, but to float above other windows.

Comment: have you tried enabling "hide the launcher" in settings? This will make the launcher invisible until you hover over where it would normally be. This might make maximized windows expand to your full resolution.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention, but I don't want the launcher to hide, but to float above other windows.

Comment: This is not possible with the current version of the dock. It would, functionally, not be ideal because controls of your application may be covered. This can be achieved in xfce with the panel settings, and probably also in Mate.